drag and drop for list
.Add drag feature for list
On this page, I want when I click on the drag icon in long press mode, the three dots icon of the boxes will disappear and the drag icon will appear in its place and enter the drag mode and the user can move the boxes and then save the changes with the save button. Please complete my code. Thank you
Long press mode is created and then with touch icon drag, three deletion points and drag icon are created for the boxes, but in that mode I cannot move and save the boxes.

class CategoryListScreenState extends State<CategoryListScreen> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> categories = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredCategories = [];
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool isSearching = false;
  bool areCheckboxesVisible = false; // اضافه کردن این متغیر
  bool selectAll = false; // برای انتخاب همه
  List<bool> selectedCategories = []; // ذخیره وضعیت انتخاب چک‌باکس‌ها
  bool isLongPressActive = false;
  bool isDraggingEnabled = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestStoragePermission(); // درخواست مجوز را در initState فراخوانی کنید
    fetchCategories();
    searchController.addListener(() {
      filterCategories();
    });
  }

  Future<void> requestStoragePermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;

    if (!status.isGranted) {
      status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
      if (status.isGranted) {
        _logger.i("مجوز دسترسی به حافظه داده شد."); // استفاده از logger
      } else {
        _logger.e("مجوز دسترسی به حافظه داده نشد."); // استفاده از logger
      }
    } else {
      _logger
          .i("مجوز دسترسی به حافظه قبلاً داده شده است."); // استفاده از logger
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // پاک‌سازی لیسنر جستجو
    searchController.removeListener(filterCategories);

    // بازنشانی متغیرها
    searchController.clear();
    isSearching = false;
    areCheckboxesVisible = false;
    selectedCategories = List<bool>.filled(categories.length, false);
    selectAll = false;

    super.dispose();
  }

  void fetchCategories() async {
    final db = await BDatabase.instance.database;
    final result = await db.query('Category');
    setState(() {
      categories = result;
      filteredCategories = categories;
      selectedCategories = List<bool>.filled(categories.length, false);
      selectAll = false;
    });
  }

  void filterCategories() {
    final query = searchController.text.toLowerCase();
    setState(() {
      filteredCategories = categories.where((category) {
        final title = category['title'].toLowerCase();
        return title.contains(query);
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  void toggleCheckbox(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      selectAll = value;
      selectedCategories = List<bool>.filled(
          categories.length, value); // به‌روزرسانی وضعیت چک‌باکس‌ها
    });
  }

  void handleMenuSelection(
      BuildContext context, String value, int categoryId, String currentTitle) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'edit':
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return EditCategoryNameDialog(
              currentTitle: currentTitle,
              categoryId: categoryId,
            );
          },
        ).then((_) {
          fetchCategories(); // به‌روزرسانی لیست دسته‌بندی‌ها بعد از ویرایش
        });
        break;
      case 'delete':
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return DeleteCategoryDialog(
              categoryName: currentTitle,
              categoryId: categoryId,
            );
          },
        ).then((_) {
          fetchCategories(); // به‌روزرسانی لیست دسته‌بندی‌ها بعد از حذف
        });
        break;
      case 'share':
        // ایجاد یک نمونه از کلاس CategoryFileSharer
        CategoryFileSharer fileSharer =
            CategoryFileSharer(context, categoryId, currentTitle);

        // فراخوانی متد shareCategoryFiles
        fileSharer.shareCategoryFiles();
        break;

      case 'companyDetails':
        // نمایش دیالوگ جزئیات شرکت
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CompanyDetailsDialog(
              categoryId: categoryId,
            );
          },
        );
        break;
      case 'editCompanyDetails':
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return EditCompanyDetailsDialog(
              categoryId: categoryId,
            );
          },
        ).then((_) {
          fetchCategories(); // به‌روزرسانی لیست دسته‌بندی‌ها بعد از ویرایش
        });
        break;
      case 'categoryDetails':
        // نمایش دیالوگ جزئیات کتگوری
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CategoryDetailsDialog(
              categoryId: categoryId,
            );
          },
        );
        break;
      case 'addToFavorites':
        // Handle add to favorites action
        break;
    }

  }

  void saveChanges() async {
    final db = await BDatabase.instance.database;
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredCategories.length; i++) {
      await db.update(
        'Category',
        {'order': i},
        where: 'id = ?',
        whereArgs: [filteredCategories[i]['id']],
      );
    }
    categories = List.from(filteredCategories);
    _logger.i("تغییرات ترتیب دسته‌بندی‌ها ذخیره شد.");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // بررسی باز بودن دراور
        if (_scaffoldKey.currentState?.isDrawerOpen ?? false) {
          // بستن دراور اگر باز است
          _scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
          return false; // جلوگیری از خروج
        }

        // بررسی فعال بودن حالت جستجو
        if (isSearching) {
          setState(() {
            isSearching = false;
            searchController.clear(); // پاک کردن متن جستجو
            filteredCategories = categories; // بازگرداندن به لیست اصلی
          });
          return false; // جلوگیری از خروج
        }

        // در صورتی که هیچکدام از شرایط بالا برقرار نباشند، اجازه خروج از صفحه می‌دهیم
        return true;
      },
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Consumer2<BackgroundImageNotifier, RestoreBackupNotifier>(
          builder:
              (context, backgroundImageNotifier, restoreBackupNotifier, child) {
            return Scaffold(
              drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 220), // Adds space from the left edge
                        Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              'BDocs',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5), // Increased space between rows
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        // متن که در سمت چپ قرار می‌گیرد
                        const Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment:
                                Alignment.center, // تنظیم مکان متن در سمت چپ
                            child: Text(
                              'لیست پروفایل‌ها', // متن ثابت
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        // آیکون در سمت راست
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(isSearching ? Icons.close : Icons.search),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (isSearching) {
                              searchController
                                  .clear(); // پاک کردن متن و بستن جستجو
                              setState(() {
                                isSearching = false; // غیرفعال کردن حالت جستجو
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                isSearching = true; // فعال کردن حالت جستجو
                              });
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                toolbarHeight: 90, // Adjusted AppBar height
                automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
              ),
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: backgroundImageNotifier.backgroundImagePath != null
                      ? DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(
                            File(backgroundImageNotifier.backgroundImagePath!),
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      : null, // اگر تصویر پس‌زمینه وجود نداشت، هیچ چیزی نمایش نده
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    if (areCheckboxesVisible)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Container(
                          // تنظیمات پس‌زمینه
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white, // رنگ پس‌زمینه سفید
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(15), // گرد کردن گوشه‌ها
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                              2.0), // فضای داخلی برای آیکن‌ها
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(width: 4),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    areCheckboxesVisible =
                                        false; // مخفی کردن چک‌باکس‌ها
                                    selectAll =
                                        false; // بازنشانی وضعیت انتخاب همه
                                    selectedCategories = List<bool>.filled(
                                        filteredCategories.length,
                                        false); // اطمینان از تطابق با تعداد آیتم‌ها
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (selectAll) {
                                      toggleCheckbox(false); // لغو انتخاب همه
                                    } else {
                                      toggleCheckbox(true); // انتخاب همه
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 6.0), // کاهش فضای داخلی
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  selectAll ? 'لغو انتخاب ' : 'انتخاب همه',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15), // تنظیم اندازه فونت
                                  overflow: TextOverflow
                                      .ellipsis, // جلوگیری از overflow متن
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 2),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // فراخوانی تابع نمایش دیالوگ حذف گروهی
                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // فراخوانی تابع اشتراک‌گذاری گروهی
                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.copy),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // عملیات کپی
                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.star),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // عملیات ستاره‌دار کردن
                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    areCheckboxesVisible =
                                        false; // مخفی کردن چک‌باکس‌ها
                                    isLongPressActive =
                                        false; // غیرفعال کردن حالت انتخاب
                                    isDraggingEnabled =
                                        true; // فعال کردن حالت جابجایی
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    // نمایش دکمه‌های ذخیره و لغو در حالت جابجایی
                    if (isDraggingEnabled)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isDraggingEnabled = false; // ذخیره تغییرات
                                });
                              },
                              child: const Text('ذخیره'),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 8),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isDraggingEnabled = false; // لغو تغییرات
                                });
                              },
                              child: const Text('لغو'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    // جعبه جستجو
                    if (isSearching)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                              0.9, // تعیین عرض باکس به 80% عرض صفحه
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9), // رنگ کمرنگ
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(10), // گرد کردن گوشه‌ها
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color:
                                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1), // رنگ سایه
                                blurRadius: 8, // میزان محو شدن سایه
                                offset: const Offset(0, 4), // فاصله سایه
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: searchController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'جستجو...',
                              border: InputBorder.none, // حذف کادر اطراف
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16,
                                  vertical: 12), // padding داخلی
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    // لیست دسته‌بندی‌ها
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                            15.0), // فاصله داخلی بین لیست و مرزها
                        itemCount:
                            filteredCategories.length, // تعداد آیتم‌های لیست
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final category = filteredCategories[
                              index]; // دسترسی به دسته‌بندی فعلی
                          return GestureDetector(
                            key: ValueKey(
                                category['id']), // کلید برای شناسایی آیتم‌ها
                            onLongPress: () {
                              setState(() {
                                areCheckboxesVisible = true; // نمایش چک‌باکس‌ها
                              });
                            },
                            onTap: () {
                              // انتقال categoryId به صفحه DocumentListScreen
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => DocumentListScreen(
                                    categoryId: category[
                                        'id'], // ارسال categoryId به صفحه جدید
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 2), // فاصله عمودی بین باکس‌ها
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 12), // فضای داخلی باکس
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                  0.9, // تنظیم عرض به 90% عرض صفحه
                              height: 50.0, // ارتفاع ثابت برای باکس
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white, // رنگ پس‌زمینه باکس
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    13), // میزان گردی گوشه‌های باکس
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(
                                        0.1), // رنگ سایه با شفافیت 10%
                                    spreadRadius: 2, // اندازه گسترش سایه
                                    blurRadius: 5, // میزان محو شدن سایه
                                    offset: const Offset(
                                        0, 1), // فاصله سایه از باکس
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                // وسط‌چین کردن محتوای داخلی به صورت عمودی و افقی
                                child: ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 0), // حذف فاصله داخلی پیش‌فرض
                                  title: Text(
                                    category['title'], // عنوان دسته‌بندی
                                    textAlign:
                                        TextAlign.right, // راست‌چین کردن متن
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, // رنگ متن
                                      fontSize: 18.0, // اندازه متن
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, // ضخامت متن
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  leading: !isDraggingEnabled
                                      ? PopupMenuButton<String>(
                                          onSelected: (value) {
                                            handleMenuSelection(
                                              context,
                                              value,
                                              category['id'],
                                              category['title'],
                                            );
                                          },
                                          // منوی سه‌نقطه
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return [
                                              const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                                value: 'edit',
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text('ویرایش نام'),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 8),
                                                    Icon(Icons.edit,
                                                        color: Colors.blue),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                            *****
,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ];
                                          },

                                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                            minWidth: 100, // حداقل عرض
                                            maxWidth: 180, // حداکثر عرض
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : const Icon(Icons
                                          .drag_handle), // آیکن درگ در غیر این صورت
                                  trailing: areCheckboxesVisible
                                      ? Checkbox(
                                          value: selectedCategories[index],
                                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              selectedCategories[index] = value ??
                                                  false; // به‌روزرسانی وضعیت چک‌باکس
                                              // به‌روزرسانی selectAll بر اساس چک‌باکس‌های فردی
                                              selectAll = !selectedCategories
                                                  .contains(false);
                                            });
                                          },
                                        )
                                      : null,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                              newIndex -= 1; // جابجایی ایندکس‌ها
                            }
                            final item = filteredCategories.removeAt(oldIndex);
                            filteredCategories.insert(
                                newIndex, item); // جابجایی آیتم
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35, left: 280),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return const AddCategoryDialog();
                      },
                    ).then((_) {
                      fetchCategories();
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

